# gmon.out is not created when executable forks another executable

Tags: c++, linux, g++, gprof

I am using gprof for profiling. But gmon.out is not created when I fork another executable inside the main executable which is compiled with option -pg. Any idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But gmon.out is not created when I fork another executable

It probably does. It simply has the same name as all the other `gmon.out` files. They just silently overwrite each other.

GNU, in all its infinite wisdom, recommends that each child process that you want to profile be executed in its own current directory. Use `mkdir` and `chdir` in your code as needed. Since `gmon.out` is written out as the process finishes, it is only necessary to `chdir` before calling `exit`.

I also recommend looking at `valgrind`. Among other nice things, it has its output files named `something.somethingelse.$PID`.

Comment: Same recommendation from IBM (AIX): https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/performance_tools/man/gprof.txt "Profiling with the fork and exec subroutines" section, "*.. one way around this problem is to call the `chdir` subroutine to change the current directory of the child process.*"

Answer (score 3):

when you set the `GMON_OUT_PREFIX=some_file_name` environment variable, gprof will create additional gmon files for each child process with the name `some_file_name.pid`.